# Retrieve document id when mapping through a collection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

**Goal**: Retrieve document id value so I can pass it into `doc()`

My document structure is as follows:

```
imageUrl: HTTP://wwww.google.com/images/23123
status: true
```

I'm mapping through my collection in firestore with...

```js
 {artworks.map((artwork) => (
          <ReviewCard
            imageUrl={artwork.imageUrl}
          />
        ))}
```

Here is my code for getting the id of this document...

```js
const handleApproval = (e) => {
    db.collection("artworks").doc(doc.id).update({ status: "true" });
  };
```

I keep receiving the error `'doc' is not defined  no-undef`

When I put the `doc.id` with the actual doc string, it works.

How can I automatically pull the doc id?

Comment: I'm not clear what you mean by "automatically pull the doc id".  Either you know the value and pass it to `doc()`, or you make a query against the collection as a whole.

Comment: Hi Doug! Okay, so I know the id from looking at the doc in firebase. However, I want to insert the doc id into to the ```doc.id``` field when I loop through the entire collection. Should I just auto generate an id when I create the collection and disregard the one automatically generated by firebase?

Comment: Are you saying you want the ID of each document as a field within that document?  If so, that's not at all clear from your question.  You might want to rewrite it to explain what your goal is.

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify. I want the value of the document id so I can pass it into doc()

Comment: Well, as I said, either you know the document ID ahead of time, or you do a query.  How else would Firestore know what document you want to update? You're going to have to provide it to handleApproval somehow, but we can't see how that's call or what data you're dealing with at that point.  If you can't provide it to handleApproval, then you're stuck, and you'll need to completely rethink how you want this code to work.

Comment: Alright, I think the query method will work best. I'll query before the handleApproval and then use the query for the doc() value. Thanks again!

Comment: My guess is that you're already loading the data for the `ReviewCard` objects from Firestore, but didn't share thst code. That is unfortunate, as that is the place where you can also get the document ID from.

Answer (score 0):

Posting this as Community Wiki, based in the discussion on comments.

As clarified, you will either to know the document ID or perform a query to gather the ID, so you can use it further. This way, you will be able to update the exact document you want. Once you have the ID, you will provide it to your `handleApproval`, so the update occurs correctly. As stated, the best and most complete option is to query before the `handleApproval` for the IDs and then use the query for the `doc()` value.